# Creating interpreter with python and want to read from file instead of shell commands

Tags: python

I'm making an interpreter with python (following a tutorial) and want to read from a file instead of writing into shell (tutorial only shows how to input to shell).

I've tried using `def load_file(filename)` but it's probably not that easy to change the code and it doesn't work

Main run function, tried adding :

```
def open_file(filename):
    data = open(filename, "r").read()
    return data

def run(fn, text):

    data = open_file(argv[0])
....
```

Current function that works using shell:

```
def run(fn, text):

    # Generate tokens
    lexer = Lexer(fn, text)
    tokens, error = lexer.make_tokens()
    if error: return None, error

    # Generate AST
    parser = Parser(tokens)
    ast = parser.parse()
    if ast.error: return None, ast.error

    # Run program
    interpreter = Interpreter()
    context = Context('<program>')
    context.symbol_table = global_symbol_table
    result = interpreter.visit(ast.node, context)

    return result.value, result.error
```

Shell.py:

```
import litas

while True:
    text = input('litas > ')
    result, error = litas.run('<stdin>', text)

    if error: print(error.as_string())
    elif result: print(result)
```

Comment: `argv[0]` is usually the program name, perhaps `argv[1]`?

Comment: You might also want to look at the `fileinput` module.

Comment: Tried, still the same. It's a 1000+ lines of code, perhaps there is more to look into the code, but I'm not gonna put this much code here. Maybe someone could help in private, check the code. I do not know python well, and it's a long story why I need this interpreter done haha

Comment: I would like only to make a little off-topic note here: `tokens, error = lexer.make_tokens()` is a bad practice of compiler/interpreter design. 

Imagine you want to interpret code received from a client through a TCP connection. Buffering all of the input for the lexer or all of the tokens for the parser might create a security hole and possibility to exploit your application with DOS attack. 

It is better when the parser asks for one token from the lexer and the token is created only when it's needed. It will be also less memory-consuming.

Comment: As currently written, `run()` processes one line of code in a variable called `text`. Your modified version loads multiple lines of code into a variable called `data`. What does it do with `data` afterward? Or are you getting an error when you try to create `data`?